# Array comparison failure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Long story short. Why is

```
 console.log(obj.hello[0].w == ['hi','hi']); // false
```

in the following:

```
var obj = {
'hello':[
    {'w':['hi','hi']}
    ]
}
console.log(obj.hello[0].w);                // ['hi','hi']
console.log(obj.hello[0].w == ['hi','hi']); // false ??? Why is it false?
console.log(obj.hello[0].w[0] == 'hi');     // true
console.log(obj.hello[0].w[0] == ['hi']);   // true
console.log(obj.hello[0].w[0] === ['hi']);  // false
console.log(obj.hello[0].w[0] === 'hi');    // true
```

If `obj.hello[0].w != ['hi','hi']`, then what is the 'real' value of `obj.hello[0].w`?

EDIT: I first thought the problem was about JSON but it turned out it's about comparing objects. Sorry, for duplicate.

Comment: ['hi','hi'] != ['hi','hi']

Comment: @mics: i think he already knows that and is asking why

Comment: @mkoryak You might be right. But I understand that he asked why array.hello[0].w != ['hi','hi'], not why ['hi','hi'] != ['hi','hi'], So I gave OP little hint.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript

Comment: I first thought the problem was about JSON but it turned out it's about comparing objects. Sorry, for duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare arrays like if they were simple variables. You're comparing references to two different arrays, and that will always be false, regardless of their contents.

If you want to do the check, you will have to compare each value individually.

Comment: Although it could be reasonable to expect it since strings are compared by their contents too. :P

Comment: That's right, but he's comparing the arrays as whole, not the strings in them.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @MightyPork's answer, there are workarounds that are very simple.

The easiest way (supported by modern browsers) is to use `JSON.stringify()`.

```
JSON.stringify(['hi', 'hi')) === JSON.stringify(['hi', 'hi')) // true
```

If your browser [doesn't support JSON nativley](http://caniuse.com/json) you can include the [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library on your page, which has the same syntax.

This isn't a complete solution.  For example, functions always return `null`, except when they are class instances.

```
function a(){ this.val = "something"; }
JSON.stringify([a]) // "[null]"
JSON.stringify([new a]) // "[{"val":"something"}]"
```